# cudaMemcpy D2D flag - semantics w.r.t. multiple devices, and is it necessary?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, memcpy, multi-gpu

I've not had the need before to memcpy data between 2 GPUs. Now, I'm guessing I'm going to do it with `cudaMemcpy()` and the `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice` flag, but:

- is the `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice`  flag used both for copying data within a single device's memory space and between the memory spaces of all devices?

If it is,

- How are pointers to memory on different devices distinguished? Is it using the specifics of the [Unified Virtual Address Space](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#unified-virtual-address-space) mechanism?

And if that's the case, then

- Why even have the H2D, D2H, D2D flags at all for cudaMemcpy? Doesn't it need to check which device it needs to address anyway?
- Can't we implement a flag-free version of cudaMemcpy using [`cuGetPointerAttribute()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__UNIFIED.html#group__CUDA__UNIFIED_1g0c28ed0aff848042bc0533110e45820c) from the CUDA low-level driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For devices with UVA in effect, you can use the mechanism you describe.  [This doc section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#peer-to-peer-memory-copy) may be of interest (both the one describing device-to-device transfers as well as the subsequent section on UVA implications).  Otherwise there is a `cudaMemcpyPeer()` [API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g88fd1245b2cb10d2d30c74900b7dfb9c) available, which has somewhat different semantics.

> How are pointers to memory on different devices distinguished? Is it using the specifics of the Unified Virtual Address Space mechanism?

Yes, see the previously referenced doc sections.

> Why even have the H2D, D2H, D2D flags at all for cudaMemcpy? Doesn't it need to check which device it needs to address anyway?

`cudaMemcpyDefault` is the transfer flag that was added when UVA first appeared, to enable the use of generically-flagged transfers, where the direction is inferred by the runtime upon inspection of the supplied pointers.

> Can't we implement a flag-free version of cudaMemcpy using cuGetPointerAttribute() from the CUDA low-level driver?

I'm assuming the generically-flagged method described above would meet whatever needs you have (or perhaps I'm not understanding this question).

Such discussions could engender the question "Why would I ever use anything but `cudaMemcpyDefault`"?

1. One possible reason I can think of to use an explicit flag would be that the runtime API will do explicit error checking if you supply an explicit flag. If you're sure that a given invocation of `cudaMemcpy` would always be in a H2D transfer direction, for example, then explicitly using `cudaMemcpyHostToDevice` will cause the runtime API to throw an error if the supplied pointers do not match the indicated direction. Whether you attach any value to such a concept is probably a matter of opinion.
2. As a matter of lesser importance (IMO) code that uses the explicit flags does not depend on UVA being available, but such execution scenarios are "disappearing" with newer environments

Comment: So just to be clear - `cudaMemcpy(... cudaMemcpyDefault)` will do peer-to-peer copy and intra-device copying when the devices support UVA?

Comment: intra-device, yes.   between separate devices, yes. To enable GPUDirect v2 P2P, you should explicitly enable P2P before doing the transfer.  Refer to the P2P sample codes.